# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: id() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'member'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, keyword-argument

I am trying to do a command for my discord bot that responds with the ID of a discord member **not in the server.** the usage would be: `!id example#0001`, the bot would then send `example#0001` and then the ID of the user. My code is:

```py
@client.command()
async def id(ctx, *, message, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    message = await ctx.send(message)
    message.content = member
    await ctx.send(f"{member.id}")
```

Comment: Do `(ctx, member:discord.Member):` as the header of the function.

Comment: @12944qwerty are you sure that would work? I think i need to define message too.

Comment: No you don't need to. `message` is only used in `on_message` events. You can easily get the message from `ctx.message` instead (as you have). You can also just send `str(member)` as that gives the Member's disc and name.

Comment: @12944qwerty thank you for letting me know, but now its saying the member is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for ?

```
@client.command()
async def id(ctx, *, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}: id = {member.id}')
```

This is a pretty simple solution

Answer (score 0):

By specifying an argument as a keyword argument, you're telling discordpy to pass in the appropriate text all into that argument. (All positional arguments are parsed first though). However, the second keyword argument: `member` is empty because discordpy doesn't have anything to put into that argument.

Also, I believe you are confusing `message` arg with the `on_message` events. You do not need that in a command, the only required argument in a command is `Context`. You can get the message object from `ctx.message.

When using a model as an annotation, you must mention that type of model. In this case, you'd have to mention the user. However, you can also use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#converters). Using a converter will parse name#disc, ID, and mention to return a member object.

Finally, you can just send `str(member)` to get `name#disc` format.
I have no idea what you wanted to do by assigning `message.content`. It would do absolutely nothing.

```py
@client.command()
async def id(ctx, member:commands.MemberConverter):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"str(member)\n{member.id}")
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help, but it is still saying that the member is not found, am I supposed to mention the member?

Comment: @ineedhelp Yes, you are supposed to. However, I updated my answer so that you don't have to always mention it for it to work